# How to install magento in subsfolder of localhost

Tags: magento

I am installing magento from our server to my localhost. I think I am gone through the process successfully. However, the css and js files are trying to referencing from the root of the localhost rather than the sub folder where it is installed.

I have executed the following two sql commands successfully without any effects

```
 Delete from core_config_data where path = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain';

 update core_config_data set value="http://127.0.0.1/xxxx/web/" where path='web/secure/base_url' or path='web/unsecure/base_url';
```

I have also deleted everything inside var.

Please find attached two images to show the issues

[image: source showing the links pointing to root of the localhost]
[image: my folder structure clearly showing the files are in subfolder/subfolder/web]

[image: secure and unsecure config as seen from admin section]
After changing the admin password, I was able to login to admin section. But the css and js files (aka skin files) are still still trying to reference from

```
http://127.0.0.1/skin...
```

whereas it should be as

```
http://127.0.0.1/xxx/web/skin/...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the base url which is usually done via admin from here:

- System
- Configuration
- General
- Web
- Unsecure / Secure
- Base URL

Since your admin is also inaccessible you will need to update it from SQL:

- Open SQL admin software
- Choose the Magento DB
- Choose table `core_config_data`
- Update the rows where the path is equal to `web/unsecure/base_url` or `web/secure/base_url`

Or run the following SQL queries:

```
update core_config_data
    set value = 'http://domainname/'
    where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

update core_config_data
    set value = 'http://domainname/'
    where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Comment: I can not access the admin section as you can see that all js and css files are trying to reference the root and not the folder structure. Also I have executed the sql commands that basically does that

Comment: After executing the SQL command that does that make sure you remove the cached files (`var/cache/*`).

Comment: Yes done. Still same issue. Also, I cant login to admin

Comment: Have the URLs changed in the HTML? If they have then we have another problem (bad url?) if they haven't then we have a caching problem (memcached active and configured on your local-server?).

Comment: I was able to change the admin password using http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password and login to admin section. But the main problem is still there. All css and js files are still being referenced from root folder aka http://127.0.0.1 rather than http://127.0.0.1/xxx/web/

Comment: memcached active and configured on your local-server?  How does that work and what is the solution

Comment: Memcached is a caching server. If you had Memcached installed on your computer and if you had it configured for Magento you would likely know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate

I was able to solve by doing below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127.0.0.1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xxx/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxx/web/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127.0.0.1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /xxx/web/index.php [L]
```